# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon in MOSS 2007

Tags: ribbon

I wonder if any of you might have any experience/suggestions/ideas in how to implement a ribbon control in MOSS 2007, that is identical to the version available in SP 2010

Comment: Urgh. Don't know if I admire your courage or if I feel sorry for you having this as a requirement. Anyway - you probably won't be able to to this without some HEAVY thinkering. You don't have client object model, so you are stuck with server side logic or implementing your javascript code. Know one thing: the ribbon concept has a license to it... so I don't know if Microsoft would allow a replica to be made for SP 2007. Maybe I am wrong, but you may want to have a look at that and see it it can cause a problem.